# Lipschitz continuity of 3(x-1)|x-1|

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How can I show that the function

$$
f(x)=3(x-1)|x-1|
$$

Is Lipschitz continuous? It's derivative is also unbounded, so I really don't know how to proceed, help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not globally Lipschitz but it is locally Lipschitz.

Comment: What's the difference between the two definitions?

Comment: Globally Lipschitz means there is a single Lipschitz that works on the full domain. Locally Lipschitz means that on each interval say $[-M,M]$ there is a Lipschitz constant $L$ which depends on $M$, and might blow up as $M \to \infty$.

Comment: Typo: "Globally...single Lipschitz *constant*..."

Answer (score 0):

It's not Lipschitz continuous. Consider $f$ on $(1, \infty)$, then we see that
\begin{align}
f(x)= 3(x-1)^2.
\end{align}
Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|<1
\end{align}
whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ for any $x, y \in (1, \infty)$. But, we have
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)| = 3|(x-1)^2-(y-1)^2| = 3|x-y||x+y-2|.
\end{align}
Let $x = n$ and $y = n+\frac{1}{2}\delta$, then $|x-y|<\delta$ but
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)| = \frac{3}{2}\delta |2(n-1)+\frac{1}{2}\delta|\rightarrow \infty
\end{align}
as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Hence $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

If the derivative is unbounded, the function cannot be Lipschitz Continous. You are done.